# Show progress on PFQuery iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, progress-bar, pfquery

I am retrieving data from Parse using like this method.

```
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (NSArray objects, NSError error) -> Void in

        if error == nil
        {
            self.saveEvent(objects!)
            onSuccess()
        }
        else {
            onFailure()
            self.delegate?.gotError!()
        }
    })
```

Is it possible to show progress status (10%....11%...12%..etc)? I just need something that can show progress and it become 100% when data is actually retrieved successfully.